# Redirect if binding parameters returns an error

Tags: php, mysql, error-handling, prepared-statement

I am trying to have my page redirect to another script which will display all error messages if there should be any. Here is what I am trying to do:

```
//Prepare statement    
$checkCode = $conn->prepare("SELECT COUNT(code) FROM subscribers WHERE code LIKE ?");

    if(!$checkCode){
         header('Location:'.$errorURL."?&notification=prepareFailed");
         die();
    }else{
         $checkCode->bind_param("s", $code);
              if(!$checkcode){
                   header('Location:'.$errorURL."?&notification=bindParamFailed");
                   die();
              }else{
                   $checkCode->execute();
                   if(!$checkCode){
                        header('Location:'.$errorURL."?&notification=executeFailed");
                        die();
                   else{
                        //store result in a variable etc.}
     }
```

`$conn` and `$errorURL` are obviously declared. `$code` is previously retrieved from the database.

This code redirects me to the page whose URL ends in `bindParamFailed`, therefore the error comes from the `bind_param` statement. If I comment out the `if(!$checkCode){...}` part it work like a charm.

Why is it not working? Any ideas?

Are there any other (maybe more intelligent) ways of programming such a custom error page?

Comment: `$checkcode` and `$checkCode` are two *different animals* altogether.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Uhhh... embarrassing.. that should resolve it, thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. Actually, MaGnetas and I both caught that at approx. the same time. You can accept his/her answer if it works out. If it doesn't, check out Michael's answer also.

Comment: @Fred-ii- of course, just need to wait five minutes until I can accept an answer... :)

Comment: Glad the question got resolved, *cheers*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the `$conn->prepare()` statement will return boolean `false` into the variable `$checkCode` on failure, the other calls you are making on the `$checkCode` object will not modify the object. It will still be "truthy", so `if ($checkCode)` isn't meaningful and the error states will never be entered, even if the bind/execute code fails.

Instead you need to check the values returned by those method calls for success or failure instead of checking `if ($checkCode)` again.  I'd recommend refactoring it into a chain of `if()`, each of which has the potential to redirect away.

```
//Prepare statement    
// If this fails, $checkCode will indeed be boolean false
$checkCode = $conn->prepare("SELECT COUNT(code) FROM subscribers WHERE code LIKE ?");

if(!$checkCode){
  header('Location:'.$errorURL."?&notification=prepareFailed");
  die();
}

// No need for the else because you cannot reach this code unless the previous
// block was true -- it would redirect away on error.
if (!$checkCode->bind_param("s", $code)) {
  header('Location:'.$errorURL."?&notification=bindParamFailed");
  die();
}

// Same here...
if (!$checkCode->execute()) {
  header('Location:'.$errorURL."?&notification=executeFailed");
  die();
}

// All is well, store the variable
// and perform the rest of your code...
```

This could be refactored a little more to call `header()` only once and set an error string on the prior errors.

```
//Prepare statement    
$checkCode = $conn->prepare("SELECT COUNT(code) FROM subscribers WHERE code LIKE ?");

if(!$checkCode){
  $err = "prepareFailed";
}
// On subsequent checks, test that the $err variable is still empty
// If it isn't, that section will be skipped and you'll fall through to the
// redirection header() call.
if (empty($err)) {
  if (!$checkCode->bind_param("s", $code)) {
    $err = "bindParamFailed";
  }
}
if (empty($err)) {
  if (!$checkCode->execute()) {
    $err = "executeFailed";
  }
}

// Now, if the $err string is non-empty, redirect with the message
if (!empty($err)) {
  header('Location:'.$errorURL."?&notification=$err");
  die();
}
else {
  // All is well, store the variable
  // and perform the rest of your code...
}
```

Comment: @Michael Berkowski I was just working on it again and it looks like it does not entirely work as it should. I misspelled a statement purposefully to see what would happen. All I get is a lot of php error messages of undefined variables. (The ones that I use after the misspelled statement).
What I did to resolve the problem was use `goto here;` after setting the $err variable and add `here;` before the following if statement: `if(!empty($err)){...}`
Is this a good approach/are there any problems with it

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Yes, just to check what would happen. See my updated comment, I accidentally pressed enter :S

Comment: @Lupy Okay, I think I see why - if the prepare fails initially, the `if(empty($err) && !$checkCode...)` can't short-circuit and `$checkCode` would be undefined. I nested the `if (empty($err))` above. There are other ways too --  I do _not_ like the idea of using `goto` even though it is probably harmless.  Some future person will read the code and critcize you for it :)

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Sorry, still doesn't work :( Why is `goto` a bad idea?

Comment: @Lupy `goto` encourages flow control shortcuts when it is usually possible to avoid by fixing the logic -- [people dislike it intensely](http://xkcd.com/292/).  What exact errors do you get? You don't have all this wrapped in `try/catch` do you?

Comment: oh sorry - this is MySQLi not PDO, so you probably aren't throwing exceptions. For what it's worth, I just hooked this code (my second example using `$err) up to one of my databases and it does work as expected. The prepare fails and falls through to the redirection.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Now I managed to get it to work! Could you explain a little as to why the original approach did not work?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Also, if I don't use the same kind of error handling on `$checkCode->close();` I get the following error: `Call to a member function close() on a non-object`. The reason why I don't want to close it is because (from what I know) it closes automatically. So there is really no point in redirecting and stopping the script if it would work just fine even though there is an error...
I changed code to cod in the prepare statement to get the error

Comment: @Lupy The original failed because on failure of `prepare()`, $checkCode` was false rather than an object. So doing `if (empty($err) && !$checkCode->bind_param(,,,))` attempts to call `bind_param()`. Since the previous call failed, `$checkCode` isn't an object and has no `bind_param()` method. Instead, the call had to be isolated in a different block than `if (empty($err))`.

Comment: Regarding `close()` it is not usually necessary to do close it manually. That only needs to be done when you have to cautiously manage memory. I would just omit it entirely. You could use `if ($checkCode) $checkCode->close();` but I just wouldn't bother

Answer (score 0):

This might be because of case sensitive variable names. First you use $checkCode  = ... (camel case) and ghen you check if ($checkcode) (lowercase). Maybe the lowercase var is simply undefined...